# Why does SQL Server not preserve the data type in expressions?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am using an expression in an Access query. It goes something like this:

```
([salary] * 50) + 4 as expr1
```

`[salary]` is of `currency` datatype. When I execute my query, `expr1` turns into `currency` as well.

However, when I do the same thing in SQL Server:

```
([salary] * 50) + 4 as expr1
```

where `[salary]` is of `money` datatype, `expr1` comes out as number datatype.

Is this common with SQL Server? That is, does SQL Server not consider the datatype preservation during arithmetic operation?

Edit:

I know that I can use `CAST` function to convert `expr1` to `money` datatype like this:

```
 CAST(([salary] * 50) + 4 AS MONEY) AS expr1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a question of datatype preservation, but a question of datatype precedence.
SQL Server is quite precise when it comes to datatypes: In SQL Server, to guarantee predictable and expect result datatype there are explicit conversions `(CAST, CONVERT)` and implicit conversions.
In your case both 50 and 4 are INT, and the salary column gets converted to INT based on the implicit rules. From MSDN: 
...

> the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher
>   precedence.

This is what happens in your case, money -> int.

The list of datatypes is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Does Access not have Datatype precedence?

Comment: Yes, access does. I believe it follows VBA. Note that ([Salary] * 50]) does return a currency for me (linked view.  (([Salary] * 50]) + 4 also returns a currency type. If you go (([Salary] * 50]) + 4.0 (note the .0) you get a number type, but NOTE carefully that it is a "decimal" type. A packed decimal type is a NOT  floating number, but is like a currency data type (a integer with a decimal position - that means no rounding errors also). I find that in most cases, this is not a issue. So it does return number type, but is NOT a floating number - but a packed decimal type.